# Align text on footer at the same line

Tags: html, css

Please look at this picture it will explain much better
https://gyazo.com/333fc2ef04f558480386b7be67eb1bda

I have a orange footer at the bottom of my webpage and i want the text to be aligned "left", "center" and "right" on the same line within the footer bar.

Right now the text is aligned but the text 3 aligns are under each other at 3 seperatly lines.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="footer">
    <div align="left"><h3>Contact</h3></div>
    <div align="center"><h3>Computerbasen</h3></div>
    <div align="right"><h3>Info</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #FF7633;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Okay wait i will edit sorry

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for this type of layout.

Remove the `align` attributes and add this to your `#footer`.

```
#footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it in many different ways.

@Vestride gave you one way.

Another approach is to add another selector :

```
#footer div{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
```

OR

```
#footer div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

This will select all `div` inside `#footer` and align them. 
We divided the three `div` width to be aligned even. So, since `width: 100%` is even. we need to subtract 10% from it to use it for margin, and the rest will be divided by 3. so each div will be 30% of the footer width. This way it will be on the same line. Remember, any element has 100% of width will be on a separate line. Meaning, if two DIVs in the same line have 100% of width, they'll be under each other, but if the width divided between them (each one of them is 50% width) then they will be at the same line.

You could use the same idea, and be creative in your own way. As there are a various of methods that can be achieved differently in CSS. Just pick your favorite one to do it.